# Blue Selector - iPhone

Tags: iphone, xcode, selector, didselectrowatindexpath

How can you turn the blue selector to go off when I move back into the view? At the moment, when I select it, I get pushed to another view. However, when I go back into the original view, it is still selected.

[image]

How can I turn it off when I go back onto the original view?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can also try this

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"myCellId";
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
    cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;

}
// Set up the cell...
cell.textLabel.text = @"foo";
return cell;
}
```

Comment: Then you have no selector at all, bad practice imo

Answer (score 3):

In your `tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:` method you should include the following:

```
[tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];
```

Comment: Thanks - really big help. I also found out you can make the arrow appear using storyboard.

Comment: This is something that Apple will reject your app for - it's part of their UI guidelines that it should deselect

Answer (score 0):

I "always" deselect the rows when the view disappears:

```
-(void)viewDidDisappear:(BOOL)animated {
    int i = 0;
    while (YES) {
        NSIndexPath *path = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:i++ inSection:0];
        if ([yourTable cellForRowAtIndexPath:path] == nil) { break; }
        [yourTable deselectRowAtIndexPath:path animated:NO];
    }
}
```

*Haven't checked the code*